# Testing Windows RemoteApps without Remote Desktop Services

Tags: windows-server-2012, windows-server-2016, remote-desktop-services, remoteapp

I want to run an app under ReportApps but at the moment I don't have access to a server with Remote Desktop Services working.

Is it possible to make the RDP setup to test RemoteApps on either a separate Windows 10 machine or a version of Windows Server (2012 / 2016)?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is. Use [RDPWrapper](https://github.com/stascorp/rdpwrap/) to circumvent RDP connection- and licensing issues on your Windows 8/10/2012/2016 machines.

Comment: Not quite what I'm looking for.  I need to test setup of a RemoteApp which is just a single application running.  From what I can see of RDPWrapper it allows a full RDP session and supporting desktop.

Comment: RemoteApp is just a full RDP Session - without the client showing explorer mainview. You can enable that in your RDC (or save it in the rdp config file), it is (technically) not a server-setting.